# BottomNavigationView link to ViewPager, when i set Listener to bottomNavigationView ,I have to click twice to perform what i do

Tags: android, kotlin

here is my code:

```
  class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    BottomNavigationViewHelper1.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView)

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        item: MenuItem ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.item_home -> {
                Log.e("Vincent", "++++++++++")
                viewpager.setCurrentItem(0, true)
                return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.item_finance -> {
                viewpager.setCurrentItem(1, true)
                return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.item_event -> {
                viewpager.setCurrentItem(2, true)
                return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.item_mine -> {
                viewpager.setCurrentItem(3, true)
                return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        true
    }
    viewpager.adapter = PagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
}
```

}

Only when I click the same tab twice , then viewpager.setCurrentItem() will perform.  But when I  use Java instead of kotlin to perform the same code ,I can get what i want.Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [`setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener)) which is only triggered when a tab is **reselected**, not the proper [`setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)) method which is called when a tab is first selected.

Comment: Thank you anyway.I had tried,but got the same result.

Comment: Can you update your code in your question with the exact copy/paste of the code you now have?

Comment: year,I just change 'bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener' into 'bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener',

Comment: Well, you should have edited your question, not added it as a comment. And you're still using the ReselectedListener, not the SelectedListener.

Comment: Sorry,It's my first time to post a question here,so I don't to know  how to format my code, Thank you .

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`

this will automatically sync both `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`